# Do we have any hack/approach for showing a column with showRowGroup=true when ag-grid is in pivot mode?

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a below column definitions:

```
{headerName: 'Country Group - No Renderer', field:'year', showRowGroup: 'year'},
{headerName: "Country", field: "country", width: 120, rowGroup: true},
{headerName: "Year", field: "year", width: 90, rowGroup: true},
{headerName: "Gold", field: "gold", width: 100, aggFunc: 'sum'},
{headerName: "Silver", field: "silver", width: 100, aggFunc: 'sum'},
{headerName: "Bronze", field: "bronze", width: 100, aggFunc: 'sum'}
```

Is there any way to show 'Country Group - No Renderer' column left to the auto grouped column along with aggregated columns when grid is in pivot mode?

Is there any possibility that we can achieve this with InMemoryModel?

Note: I am beginner to ag-grid and just now started playing with it.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Yes! By doing server side pivoting :D  instead of grid's pivot

Comment: Could you exemplify how you did this on the server side?

Comment: You can't show extra column on grid when grid is on pivot mode is the problem which i faced here.
So what i did is, I removed grids pivot in grid options and I have written a code to create dynamic column definitions in a way that i wanted to show in UI. Accordingly, pivoting on row data.